# Google map is not load properly in tab 2 and tab 3. How to create refresh tabs?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, tabs

I have 3 shop location that I wanted to show in google map. I have separate it into 3 tab and 3 google map. It was working fine at the 1st tab. But the 2nd tab and 3rd tab is not load properly. It was working fine without the tabs. I found some blog that tabs require to refresh? I am not sure how to do so but i tried and getting error. Anyone can help me out ? Thanks

Here below is my tab code:-

```
    <div class="tabbable" id="tabs-331065">
    <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="panel-127823">
                    <p>
                        <div id="map-city" ></div>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="panel-737549">
                    <p>
                        <div id="map-box"></div>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="panel-737589">
                    <p>
                        <div id="map-forest"></div>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="map-tabs">
                <li class="active" id="map-tab1">
                    <a href="#panel-127823" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">CITY</a>
                </li>
                <li id ="map-tab2">
                    <a href="#panel-737549" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">BOX HILL</a>
                </li>
                <li id="map-tab3">
                    <a href="#panel-737589" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">FOREST HILL</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
```

Google map function : -

```
<script>

    function initialize() {
      var myLatlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(-37.8122172,144.965374);
      var myLatlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(-37.818535,145.12194);
      var myLatlng3 = new google.maps.LatLng(-37.834697,145.165394);
      var mapOptions1 = {
        zoom: 17,
        center: myLatlng1
      }
      var mapOptions2 = {
        zoom: 17,
        center: myLatlng2
      }
      var mapOptions3 = {
        zoom: 17,
        center: myLatlng3
      }
      var map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-city'), mapOptions1);
      var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-box'), mapOptions2);
      var map3 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-forest'), mapOptions3);

      var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng1,
          map: map1,

      });
       var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng2,
          map: map2,

      });
       var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng3,
          map: map3,

      });
    }


    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);



        </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason is because the map is not visible for tab 2 and tab 3 (e.g. tab one is active) when you create them so they will not resize properly.

What you need to do do is in activating a tab - You need to call map resize to let the map redraw.  it will then resize based on its container.

Do something like this when you activate a tab ten pass in the map for that tab or get the correct map in the function:

First change your initialize function so you don't declare the maps inside it:

```
// declare your maps outside of the functions like this and remove 
// your var where you create them.
var map1, map2,map3;

 function initialize() {
      var myLatlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(-37.8122172,144.965374);
      var myLatlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(-37.818535,145.12194);
      var myLatlng3 = new google.maps.LatLng(-37.834697,145.165394);
      var mapOptions1 = {
        zoom: 17,
        center: myLatlng1
      }
      var mapOptions2 = {
        zoom: 17,
        center: myLatlng2
      }
      var mapOptions3 = {
        zoom: 17,
        center: myLatlng3
      }

      // Note I removed the var
      map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-city'), mapOptions1);
      map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-box'), mapOptions2);
      map3 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-forest'), mapOptions3);

      var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng1,
          map: map1,

      });
       var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng2,
          map: map2,

      });
       var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng3,
          map: map3,

      });

     // attach the tab click handler
     attachTabClick();
  }
```

Then attach a tab activate function on document ready or at the bottom of your initialize function:

```
function attachTabClick()
{

   $('.nav-tabs').bind('click', function (e) 
   {
      // e.target is the link
      // so use its parent to check which map to show

      var tabId = e.target;      

      //check the ID and only call the resize you need - 
      if(tabId == 'panel-127823')
      {
         resizeMap(map1)
      }
      else if(tabId == 'panel-737549')
      {
         resizeMap(map2);
      }
      else if(tabId == 'panel-737589')
      {
         resizeMap(map3)
      }           
    });
}
```

then call the function to resize the map:

```
function resizeMap(map)
{
   setTimeout(function()
   {
       var center = map.getCenter();
       google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
       map.setCenter(center);
   },50);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/loanburger/fzhgjfrb/

1. Note I added a slight timeout before resizing as I found that the div needed time to show properly.
2. Secondly I am calling resize for all map - you need to check the right ID and only call the resize for the map which will be visible.

Comment: <li id ="map-tab2" onclick="resizeMap();"> is it like this ?

Comment: I still not able to load my map probably after paste your update. for example, the map size is 450px width and 250 height. and my market is at center but it is hidden with grey.

Comment: Weird. I place it in my html file. is not working. and my map is missing too.

Comment: I have double check on my tabs name and everything is correct. and i get this error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of nullmain.js:44 Hjmain.js:50 zkindex-homepage.html:120 initializeindex-homepage.html:180 (anonymous function)

Comment: I have 2 jquery library.

Comment: I have recreate a new html to input all the code with jquery. No still no luck. am i missing out something?

Comment: Make sure you have referenced google maps api bootstrap,and one jquery library.  My answer is correct and working based on what you asked.  So,maybe you have a different issue.  Add a link to a JSFiddle demostrating your issue and i can take a look or post a link to your html page